# How can I Export from a report the record counts of Contacts, orders etc per account?

Tags: reporting, account, contact, record, order

I have a giant spreadsheet with all our key accounts etc and we need to find out how many orders per account, how many contacts per account.

On SF reports I can add a "Record Count" formula but when I export this doesn't come as part of the file, I need to find the easiest way to potentially use a Vlookup and update the spreadsheet with each individual record count. Is this possible? It seems like a really simple necessary thing a lot of people would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messing around with Formulas and such aside, get all the columns of data you wish to report on - Download to Excel, create a pivot table and add "orders" or "full name" to Values & then add the company name to X axis will allow you to create a pivot with results showing the total amounts of opportunities/orders/contacts then its simply using a vlookup or copy and paste matching the ID's upto the existing spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Printable View button instead of export this will keep all record counts and show the report as it appears in the salesforce report screen.

Comment: How can I use a printable view to add this back onto my spreadsheet though?

Comment: Also printable view only gives me 2000 of the 19k records

Comment: The other option is to create a Rollup summary on the account for orders and contacts and this will put a field which you can report on and export from salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en

Comment: I decided to download without any sort of filters and then just pivot table in excel, was much easier :) Thanks for taking the time to answer.